# Colimit in the category of Sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, limits-colimits

Below $\mathcal{I}\to \textbf{Set}$ is a functor(diagram) between two categories while $M_i$ are all sets. There are no restrictions on $\mathcal{I}$. I cannot see why the equivalence of elements $m_i\in M_i$ and $m_{i'}\in M_{i'}$, $m_i\sim m_{i'}$ are related to the chain of morphisms below. Isn't it just an arrow $i\to i'$? What are the $i_0,...i_{2n}$ doing here?

The image below is from [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/002U).

[image: Quote from Stacks project]

Comment: I attached the source of the image. I am assuming they mean the coproduct of sets $M_i, i\in I$ as the union $\bigcup_{i\in I} \{(i, m) : m\in M_i\}$. I also fixed the question. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: key phrase:  "generated by"

Comment: Given a relation $R$ on a set, we can can define an equivalence relation that is the smallest equivalence relation on the set that includes $R.$ Then $i_1,i_{2n}$ is just the standard way of creating that closure.

Comment: Replied to "key phrase: "generated by"": Oh I was assuming what they defined is already an equivalence relation. Let me see what is the smallest equivalence relation containing that...

Comment: Replied to "Given a relation $R$ on a set, we can can define an equivalence relation that is the smallest...": Oh that makes sense! I should have read it more carefully. Thank you all!